# xfce: How to get bottom panel (back). How to update time in the upper right corner

Tags: xfce, panel, timezone

Somehow the bottom panel isn't switched on by default. I am talking about the one you see in following picture (mouse cursor is hovering right above):

[image]

I've switched the time zone. However, the time that is shown in the upper right corner is still that from Los Angeles.

BTW, if I click the time, then "Time & Date Settings", nothing happens. Same goes for the "system settings" after clicking on the cog wheel.
Would you mind telling me the solution for that problem too?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That bottom panel is just that a panel. I think if you right click the top panel in an empty spot you can create a new panel and then move it to the bottom. See more info here: [https://www.maketecheasier.com/customize-xfce-desktop/](https://www.maketecheasier.com/customize-xfce-desktop/)

Answer (score 0):

What I see in your screenshot looks like Plank. If you want to start Plank automatically, you need to add Plank to your startup applications.

Open the System Settings and choose `Session and Startup`, there open the `Application Autostart`-tab. Now click the `Add`-button.

- in the `Name` field type `Plank`
- in the `Description` field type whatever you want or leave it empty
- in the `Command` field type `plank`

Now click `Ok`.

[image]

That's all, you're done. Now Plank will start whenever you login.

Regarding your other questions, please open a new question, the rule here is
one question per post as this is most helpful for future readers.

If you cannot open the system settings via the GUI, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the command `xfce4-session-settings`, this will directly open `Session and Startup`.